# WebStorm run all dart unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, configuration, dart, webstorm

In WebStorm 11 I want to create a run configuration which runs all dart tests in my project.

However there is no option to do this in the "Dart Test" configuration template. The only options are:

- Test Kind: All in file, Test group, single test
- Test file: must point to a .dart file, otherwise I get "Dart file is not found"
- VM Options (text input)

If I point WebStorm to a single test file this command gets executed in the test window:

```
C:\path\to\dart\bin\dart.exe --ignore-unrecognized-flags --checked --trace_service_pause_events file:\\\C:\path\to\dart\bin\snapshots\pub.dart.snapshot run test:test -r json C:/path/to/project/test/someclass_test.dart
```

I don't want to create a run configuration for every unit test class I write, there must be a better way.

Currently I prefer to navigate to the project directory and just run

```
pub run test:test
```

This runs all tests which live in files ending with _test.dart which is perfectly what I want. More info here: https://github.com/dart-lang/test#running-tests

Is there no such option in WebStorm for dart developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [WEB-14747](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14747) ticket this functionality is already implemented for the next major version.

You can try latest **EAP build of WebStorm v12** [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/02/webstorm-12-eap-144-3891/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's currently not supported.

The feature to run tests this way is quite new anyway.

If you think this feature is important, lease create a feature request in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB